# Изменение формы оплаты товара в Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Возможно ли изменить форму оплаты в шаблоне на WordPress. Так чтобы имел внешний вид как на фото.

Сейчас есть возможность оплачивать картой, но нужно чтобі была возможность оплаты в рассрочку.
И показывало первый взнос в зависимости от длительности.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это страница checkout, подскадите в каком направлении искать

Answer (score 1):

Для кастомизации страницы чекаута - скопировать из плагина woocommerce шаблоны в папку активного шаблона

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout -> wp-content/themes/активная_тема/woocommerce/chechkout/
```

Доступный набор хуков для чекаута

```
woocommerce_before_checkout_form
woocommerce_before_checkout_form
woocommerce_checkout_billing
woocommerce_checkout_shipping
woocommerce_checkout_order_review
woocommerce_checkout_order_review
```

Подробный гайд по хукам страницы чекаута

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/